# Android custom keyboard with strings

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I want to customize the inputmethod keyboard with formula. When I press the key, the `EditText` can show the string such `[#frac]`. 
How can I implement it by android:codes. Please help me. Thank you very much for you.

Comment: Code so far? SO is **not** a code writing service

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

1) [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html);

2) [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) tutorial;

3) [that](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example) simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `android:keyOutputText`

eg. in custom keyboard when you press button "123", you get text 123

```
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="55"    android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key android:codes="56"    android:keyLabel="8" />
    <Key android:codes="57"    android:keyLabel="9" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    <Key android:keyOutputText="123"  android:keyLabel="123" android:horizontalGap="6.25%p"/>
</Row>
```

[More here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:keyOutputText)